# Загрузка данных в Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Проблема в следующем:
Имеются в БД таблицы со связью некоторых таблиц многие ко многим (Отображу в виде классов EntityFramework):

```
class Device 
{ 
    .... 
     public string DeviceProperty { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<DeviceList> DeviceElementList { get; set; }
    ....
}

class Element 
{ 
    ...
     public string ElementProperty { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<DeviceElement> DeviceElementList { get; set; }
    ...
}

class DeviceElement 
{ 
   ...
   public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
   public virtual Element Element { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Загружаем данные в таблицу DataGrid, используя ленивую загрузку:

```
using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
{
    var data = from d in context.DeviceElements
                      where ...
                      select d;
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = data.ToList();
    dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```

В результате, в таблицу загружаются поля через биндинги типа

```
... Binding={Binding Path = Device.DeviceProperty} ...  и 
... Binding={Binding Path = Element.ElementProperty} ... и т.д.
```

Всё вроде хорошо, но когда строк больше 5 тысяч(в моем случае) и каждая таблица имеет минимум 10 полей, включая поля не с базовыми типами данных, то, к примеру, вывод нескольких отсортированных строк с данными может длиться около 7-10 секунд.

Решил использовать прямую загрузку, но в этом случае данные, видимо, нужно хранить где-то в кэше?

 Пробовал так:

```
using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
{
    context.DeviceElements.Load();
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = context.DeviceElements.Local.ToBindingList();
    dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Без разницы вообще!..
Как можно сделать загрузку данных в таблицу более оптимизированной что ли, чтобы не ждать такое огромное количество времени сортировку. Возможно, чтобы данные, загружались куда-то в кэш, а потом при повторной загрузке просто дописывались отсутствующие данные, либо удалялись уже отсутствующие в основной БД???.

Дополню:

При загрузке всех данных таблицы, без сортировки, загрузка проходит гораздо быстрее (секунды 2), против отсортированных данных (~7 секунд), 
т.е. если запрос вернёт только несколько строк - на это уйдет тех же 7 секунд

Comment: Загружайте частями, например, по 200 строк и догружайте по мере необходимости (при прокрутке таблицы, например). Либо организуйте что-то вроде пагинации

Comment: `используя ленивую загрузку` ... `dataGrid.ItemsSource = context.DeviceElements.ToList();` - это разве ленивая загрузка?

Comment: Коротко: использовать пагинацию, шире использовать IQueryable и `.AsNoTracking()` и проблем не будет до ~ миллиона строка в таблице.

Comment: @tym32167, прошу прощения, исправил

Comment: вы когда делаете вот так `data.ToList()` вы просто всю таблицу из БД помещаете в память, тут нет ничего ленивого.

Comment: @tym32167, почему всю? сортированную, строчка выше. В каком тогда случае у меня будет ленивая загрузка? Я считал, что строка сортировки таблицы у меня как раз создаёт и отправляет запрос, а подгружаются данные, отсортированные по этому запросу в момент вызова метода .ToList(), или это работает не так?

Comment: Lazy loading - это про загрузку связанных сущностей ([раз](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx), [два](https://habr.com/ru/post/336812/)), а вы в вашем примере просто грузите какую то таблицу в память.

Comment: @tym32167, загрузка данных DeviceElement влечет за собой загрузку сущностей Device и Element. Я не от нечего делать привёл классы сущностей.

Comment: Ну раз вы это понимаете, тогда вопросов нет. Я просто увидел ваш комментарий в коде и у меня сработал триггер :)

Comment: `Всё вроде хорошо, но когда строк больше 5 тысяч` просто ткну пальцем в небо, но в вашем гриде используется виртуализация? Может оно медленно работает, так как много элементов интерфейса создает?

Comment: @tym32167, да, используется, причём с этого и начинал в своё время плясать

Comment: @tym32167, наверное нужно было указать, но, если грузить просто все данные таблицы без сортировки - загрузка проходит всего несколько секунд, но если данные отсортировывать - минимум секунд 7

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я думаю, здесь больше проблема не в загрузке данных в саму таблицу, и её последующее отображение, а в сортировке данных перед загрузкой

Comment: мне кажется, что 5 тысяч строчек, пусть хоть по 20 полей имеют, они будут сортироваться мгновенно, уж точно не 7 секунд. Попробуйте без биндинга отсортировать их в памяти.